# Append rows from different position to a existing csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pandas-groupby

I am trying to append row in existing csv file..Ex:-

```
number name zipcode country Total_store ratings
  1    A     200201
```

To append the rows with dict method which is

```
{'country': 'htttp', 'Total_store': 'dsddsa', 'ratings': 'sfsfsf'}
```

I tried using df.to_csv(f, header=False, index=False) which is adding it to the bottom of file, but I want it to append next to zipcode in first line.
How can I do it please help..

Comment: Can you try to convert your dictionary in to a dataframe and then concat them

Comment: how can i do that please explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# 1 - Creating your original dataframe. Assume its imported from csv
tst = pd.DataFrame([{'number': 1, 'name': 'A', 'zipcode': 200201, 'country': '', 'Total_store': '', 'ratings': ''}])

# 2 - Creating your dict
md = {'country': 'htttp', 'Total_store': 'dsddsa', 'ratings': 'sfsfsf'}

# 3 - Convert dictionary to dataframe
dict_to_df = pd.DataFrame([md])

# 4 - Concat your data
res_df = pd.concat([tst[['number', 'name', 'zipcode']], dict_to_df], axis=1)
```

Here's the output:

```
    number  name    zipcode     country     Total_store     ratings
0   1       A       200201      htttp       dsddsa          sfsfsf
```

You can then export to csv using `res_df.to_csv('/path/to/save', index=False)`

[image]

Comment: can you help me with first step.I am getting csv file like this df = pd.read_csv('test.csv') and it has 200rows pre filled with number name zipcode..

Comment: In my code I created the dataframe manually for reference. You dont have to do that as you have a csv. Next step is to create a list of dictionaries like mentioned in step 2

Comment: country Total_score ratings    country Total_score ratings
0   NaN NaN NaN  htttp  dsddsa  sfsfsf
1   NaN NaN NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
3   NaN NaN NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
4   NaN NaN NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
..   ..  ..  ..    ...     ...     ...
148 NaN NaN NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
149 NaN NaN NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
150 NaN NaN NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
151 NaN NaN NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
152 NaN NaN NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN

[153 rows x 6 columns]

Comment: This is deleting my csv data

Comment: Can you share your entire code please. Difficult to debug without it

Comment: here please go to this link https://i.ibb.co/WkMtkcv/code.png

Comment: The code looks proper. I cant see the output though. I'll share a screenshot of code in my notebook

Comment: Noob, can you check the image attached in the answer

Comment: Yes, finally it's working thank you for keeping up with my stupid questions